# Как эту программу сделать короче?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Нужно выводить случайные символы в несколько столбцов.

```
import random

n = str()
n1 = str()
n2 = str()
n3 = str()
n4 = str()
n5 = str()
n6 = str()
n7 = str()
n8 = str()
n9 = str()
n10 = str()

while True:
    n = random.choice (["!", "№", "#", "$", "%", "@", "^", "&", "*"])
    n1 = random.choice (["!", "№", "#", "$", "%", "@", "^", "&", "*"])
    n3 = random.choice (["!", "№", "#", "$", "%", "@", "^", "&", "*"])
    n4 = random.choice (["!", "№", "#", "$", "%", "@", "^", "&", "*"])
    n5 = random.choice (["!", "№", "#", "$", "%", "@", "^", "&", "*"])
    n6 = random.choice (["!", "№", "#", "$", "%", "@", "^", "&", "*"])
    n7 = random.choice (["!", "№", "#", "$", "%", "@", "^", "&", "*"])
    n8 = random.choice (["!", "№", "#", "$", "%", "@", "^", "&", "*"])
    n9 = random.choice (["!", "№", "#", "$", "%", "@", "^", "&", "*"])
    n10 = random.choice (["!", "№", "#", "$", "%", "@", "^", "&", "*"])
    print(n, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import choice
a = ["!", "№", "#", "$", "%", "@", "^", "&", "*"]
n = 10 # кол-во столбцов
while True:
    for i in range(n):
        print(choice(a), end="")
    print()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `while True:` превращает вашу программу в бесконечный цикл.

Answer (score 0):

Массив можете занести в array, внутри while True сделать цикл до десяти, где можно использовать локальную переменную, выбирать рандомом из массива и выводить

Comment: Почему не добавить код, который это сделает?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

SYMBOLS = "!№#$%@^&*"
HOW_MANY = 11

random_symbols = random.choices(SYMBOLS, k=HOW_MANY)

print(random_symbols)
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Для повторного выбора случайного символа из того же самого множества лучше применить функцию `choices()` (вместо `choice()`), которая возвращает (в виде списка) *сразу только символов, сколько вы задаете в параметре `k`.*

---

*Примечание:*

Когда вам не нравится вывод в виде списка (в квадратных скобках), вы можете выводить элементы списка в цикле:

```
for symbol in random_symbols:
    print(symbol, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Аккуратный рефакторинг вашего приводит к такому результату:

```
import random

while True:
    choices = random.choices('!№#$%@^&*', k=10)
    print(*choices[:2], '', *choices[2:])
```

> ```
> $ python choices.py | head
> ! !  % $ % $ $ @ $ №
> @ №  % * & ! @ * & !
> # %  ! & @ % # № @ !
> % *  ! * @ # * @ @ #
> ! &  % ! # № @ # * !
> @ ^  & % @ @ & * № %
> ^ @  № № ^ № № ^ @ &
> ! @  ! @ № $ # @ $ №
> № %  ! ^ $ * ^ & * @
> ! ^  ^ % ^ № ! ! ! ^
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/temp.py", line 5, in <module>
>     print(*choices[:2], '', *choices[2:])
> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
> ```

Comment: `while True:` превращает вашу программу в бесконечный цикл.

Comment: @MarianD, я следовал циклу `while True:` в вопросе и фразе "Нужно выводить случайные символы в несколько **столбцов**.". Надо было сделать по другому?

Comment: Да. Например, применением цикла `for`, или по крайней мере `break` для прекращения бесконечного цикла `while True:`.